# Drupal does not support dollar sign for jQuery and its breaking my facebook?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, facebook-javascript-sdk

The moment I include the Facebook API, I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

The reason is that Drupal 7 allows:

```
jQuery(....
```

but not

```
$(....
```

But the Facebook JS API does in fact use

```
$(....
```

How can I make Drupal support $( annotation or what is the correct way to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

I'm assuming something must change here:

```
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

?

Comment: why would that be important for facebook? the init code of the javascript sdk does not use jquery (luckily).

Comment: In the javascript portion above, I am adding all.js. I would assume that is calling $(... somewhere, causing me to get the error?

Comment: Facebook does not use jQuery, so that´s not the reason. This has no relation to Facebook at all.

Comment: It seems my answer below will not be any help. I'm not very familiar with FB, but I suppose @luschn is right, it's not a jQuery problem. When you run the code, can you see the corresponding `script` tag (it'll be one with `id="facebook-jssdk"`) added to the `head` of the document?

Comment: PS I've added your code from `UPDATE` to my Drupal 7 test site (as a block with PHP filter) - no errors, all works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make Drupal support $

To make it work just wrap your code inside this function:

```
(function ($) {
  //your code, now you can use "$" with no problems
})(jQuery);
```

It's an [official suggestion](https://www.drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility).

You can do it in other ways too, though. For example, adding

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

at the beginning of JS code should work as well.

You can also use [jQuery Dollar](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_dollar) module.

Comment: This does solve my problem, but what I still don't understand is that the error is happening in a file that starts with VM and then a number. Each time I refresh, this number changes. So first it's VM1838 then VM3998 then VM3893 etc. And in that file, it calles "$(", but it almost seems like it's being run by the browser or something else. I have no idea, but it's not being included specifically withFacebook Connect.

Comment: @coderama I haven't come across this particular problem before so couldn't provide any suggestions :(